# Wyse P25 VGA port is set as display 2

Tags: vmware-esxi, thin-client, vmware-view, pcoip

I'm running VMware View 5 environment and we are using Wyse P25's to connect via PCoIP.  If we plug the monitor in to the display port everything comes up fine, but if we plug the monitor into the VGA port it shows a black screen that we assume to be set up as a secondary display.  Is there a way to set the Wyse box to auto detect or at minimum set the VGA port as default and the display port as a secondary monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether there are any display-related settings in the BIOS?
It might be possible to disable the display port completely, or switch the DP/VGA priority.

Comment: I've looked through all the settings and there isn't anything that I can tell that would allow me to disable the display port.

Comment: Maybe it's only configurable from the display settings in the OS (Windows Embedded?). Have you already contacted DELL/WYSE support about it? It could be important enough for them to include it in a firmware update, so it becomes configurable from BIOS.